# Kendo chart with date x-axis renders very slowly when baseUnit is "seconds"

Tags: performance, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

My chart has X-axis as dates, and I have some data points that are pretty close (seconds away), so I need to set baseUnits down to "seconds". But the chart renders extremely slow in this case.

I set up a sample **[here](http://jsbin.com/UCaQuti/11/edit)**:     right now date range is set to 1 week, it's already slow. please change the categoryAxis.max to see the performance issue.

Is there a better way to do this? I thought about scatterLine, but I also have some bar series to put to the same chart.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would like to know the answer for this question as well...